# Python Sequence of Numbers

Tags: python, list, sequence

I've decided not to waste my summer and start learning python.  I figured I'd start learning looping techniques so I wanted to start with a basic list of numbers, aka, write a for loop that will generate the numbers 1 - 10.

This is what I have:

```
def generateNumber(num):
    i=0 
for i in range(num):
    return i
return i
```

and the code doesn't work.  I want to get an output in a list like this:

```
>>> generateNumber(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Trying to be consistent with what you first tried, you could do something like this

```
def generateNumber(num):
    mylist = []
    for i in range(num+1):
         mylist.append(i)
    return mylist


x = generateNumber(10)
```

but, you could, instead just say,

```
x = range(10+1)  # gives a generator that will make a list
```

or

```
x = list(range(10+1))  # if you want a real list
```

In general though, you should keep this list based on inputting the number 10 so it is [0...9] and not [0...10].

Comment: You may want to return something from your function :)

Comment: Your two examples are Python3 specific

Comment: @TankorSmash Er... what part is?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Just a small part, `range` in Py3k is Py2's `xrange` in that it returns a generator, while in Py2's `range` returns a list.

Comment: Why in the name of all that is sensible does Python require a custom function for this??

Answer (score 3):

It might help to implement this with the ability to specify a range:

```
def generateNumber(low, high):
    '''returns a list with integers between low and high inclusive
    example: generateNumber(2,10) --> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    '''
    return range(low, high+1)
```

This can also be done with the built-in range function:

```
range(10)   --> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]   #note the "off by one"
range(11)   --> [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
range(2,11) --> [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

More about range:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Comment: Why `[x for x in xrange(low, high+1)]` instead of just `range(low, high+1)` or `list(xrange(low, high+1))`?

Comment: Just updated, thanks.  There was no reason to use the list comp.  The range function is much faster by itself -- it's highly optimized for this type of usage.

Answer (score 2):

By default, range(n) produces list of numbers [0, 1, ..., n-1].

If you want a list of numbers from a to b inclusive, you should call:

```
range(a, b + 1)
```

Which in your case is:

```
range(1, 11)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `range` function already does what you are setting out to do.

If you're in Python 2, `range(10)` returns 0 through 9, or in Python 3 it's `list(range(10))`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to create a list in your function, use the [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained) keyword, or use the built in [list](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) function.

```
def generateNumberList(num):
    myList = []
    for i in range(num):
        myList.append(i)
    #Notice that your return the list you've created rather 
    #than each individaul integer
    return myList

print generateNumberList(10)

def generateNumberList2(num):
    for i in range(10):
        yield i

for i in generateNumberList2(10):
    print i

def generateNumberList3(num):
    return list(range(num))

print generateNumberList3(10)
```