# How ton use python "For" loop to print number sequence

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

> How to use Loop to print numbers 8,11,14,17,......83,86.

```
for i in range(100):
i = 8
print(i+3)
```

*but this do not works*

Comment: `for i in range(8, 87, 3): print(i)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Sequence of Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175809/python-sequence-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating your variable `i`. This loop will print `i+3` (which is 11 of course) 100 times and does not update `i`.

As already mentioned, you can use the following code:

```
for i in range(8, 87, 3):
     print(i)
```

`range` will provide you with a range object (which is a kind of iterable) with all numbers between 8 and 86 with a step size of 3 (so 8, 11, 14, ...)